# handlebars - using #if helpers with two conditions

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

In my js file, I pass a JSON object with two keys - {'tests': tests, 'isComplete': isComplete}

In my handlebars file, I want to display the tests object based on each test status. At the same time, there's another condition for which I added a helper named 'isRequired' that I want to check the test against only if isComplete is not true.

```
{{#if isComplete}}
{{#each tests}}
    {{#isRequired this}}
        // display data
    {{/isRequired}}
{{/each}}
{{else}}
{{#each tests}}
    // display data
{{/each}}{{/if}}
```

This code has the duplicate code to display data. I'm still learning handlebars and not sure how to eliminate this redundant code block. Can you help me how I can refactor this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably solve this by adding an `isComplete` parameter to your `isRequired` helper. You have not provided the code for your helper, but I imagine it would end up looking something like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isRequired', function (context, isComplete, options) {
    if (!isComplete) { return options.fn(context); }
    /* rest of isRequired implementation here */
});
```

Your template would then be updated as follows:

```
{{#each tests}}
    {{#isRequired this ../isComplete}}
        // display data
    {{/isRequired}}
{{/each}}
```

Note that this implementation applies the `isRequired` logic *only if* `isComplete` is `true`. This is the same rules as exist in your template code sample. However, these rules appear to contradict the text of your question, which specifies that `isRequired` should be applied "only if isComplete is not true". If these are the requirements we must meet, we need only remove the not operator from our new guard clause:

```
 if (isComplete) { return options.fn(context); }
```

Comment: This helped.  ../ for the nested path was something I wasn't aware of. Thanks!!